# How to fill nested dictionary with values of a Queryset as a list in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a a dictionary like this:

```
result = { 'year' : {} }
```

and I have a queryset like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'building_id': 1, 'year': 2019, 'demand': 123.34}, {'building_id': 1, 'year': 2019, 'demand': 345.0}, {'building_id': 1, 'year': 2019, 'demand': 12345.0}, {'building_id': 2, 'year': 2019, 'demand': 345.0}]>
```

Now I would like to transform the values of the queryset into the nested dictionary so that it looks like so:

```
result = { 'year' : {'1' : [123.34, 345.0, ...], '2' : [345, ...] }
```

I get my queryset like this, so it is currently within a loop:

```
    for item in buildings:
        demand_cool_item = item.demandcool_set.filter(year=passed_year).values('building_id', 'year', 'demand')
```

For starters I was trying to loop through the queryset push it to an array and then update the dict within the dict like so:

```
demand_cool_list = []

    for item in buildings:
        demand_cool_item = item.demandcool_set.filter(year=passed_year).values('building_id', 'year', 'demand')
        demand_cool_list.append(demand_cool_item)


    for item in demand_cool_list:
        result.update(item)
```

tried also `result.update(item['building_id']['demand'])`

That said that dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required or that I have a Type Error. 
!
Can someone land me a hand on this? Highly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the queryset, and then append the values to the proper list, like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

year_dict = defaultdict(list)
for demand in item.demandcool_set.filter(year=passed_year):
    year_dict[demand.building_id].append(demand.demand)

result = {'year': dict(year_dict)}
```

or we can use a [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) here:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = { 'year': {
    k: [v['demand'] for v in vs]
    for k, vs in groupby(
        item.demandcool_set.filter(
            year=passed_year
        ).values('building_id', 'demand').order_by('building_id'),
        itemgetter('building_id')
    ))
  }}
```

The result will thus contain a key `'year'` that maps on a dictionary that maps `building_id`s on `demand`s.

Note that if you do not order the queryset by some timestamp, the values can appear in *any* order, and hence the order in the lists is *not* guaranteed. You thus might want to add a `.order_by(..)` clause to your queryset.

Comment: that's fantastic... absolutely fantastic....exactly what I needed.... Thanks a bunch my friend!